# Datawarehouse, ROLAP and Storage Space

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, olap, star-schema, rolap

I have a star-schema with `n` dimensions and one fact table.

Now I want to calculate the total amount of space is needed to save all the data from the star-schema in a ROLAP-Cube.

Is there like a formula or something?

Comment: You might get close with calculation field length of every column with amount of rows. Add a bit for management and subtract a bit for good table handling. Also, In-Memory engines usually compress the content quite a bit so you might up with a lot less RAM required.

Comment: Sorry maybe I used the wrong vocabulary. I meant the total amount of storage space in a database.

Comment: I'd go with the calculation approximation I provided in the first comment. It could be that some compression happens. Why would you need to calculate this?